# Concurrent az login executions

Tags: bash, azure, docker, jenkins, azure-cli

I am using the Azure CLI to perform a health check on some Azure VMs. The health checks are deployed through a Jenkins stage, using bash. The stage itself may take several hours to complete, during which, several az 'vm run-commands' are executed that all require the proper credentials.

I also have several Jenkins pipelines that deploy different products and that are supposed to be able to run in parallel. All of them have the same health checks stage.

When I execute '**az login**' to generate an auth token and '**az account set**' to set the subscription, as far as I understood, this data is written to a profile file (**~/.azure/azureProfile.json**). So this is well and all, but whenever I trigger a parallel pipeline on this Jenkins container, if I use a different Azure subscription, the profile file will naturally get overwritten with the different credentials, which causes the other health check to fail whenever it gets to the next vm run-command execution since it's looking for a Resource Group, which exists in a different subscription.

I was thinking of potentially creating a new unique Linux user as part of each stage run and then removing it once it's done, so all pipelines will have separate profile files. This is a bit tricky though, since this is a Jenkins docker container using an alpine image and I would need to create the users with each pipeline rather than in the dockerfile, which brings me to a whole other drama - to give the Jenkins user sufficient privileges to create and delete users and so on...

Also, since the session credentials are stored in the ~/.azure/accessTokens.json and azureProfile.json files by default, I could theoretically generate a different directory for each execution, but I couldn't find a way to alter those default files/location in the Azure docs.

How do you think is the best/easier approach to workaround this?

Comment: For which purpose you need to relogin in the each pipeline ? If it is just to change the subscription each Azure CLI command has `--subscription` parameter, as it is the same user for scripts it will use the same token, so you do not need to relogin or change the context if you are deploying resources to multiple subscription under the same AAD tenant

Comment: Right, so let me give you a bit more context here. The az login uses a Service Principal which has access to a single subscription. If I run a pipeline in a different subscription, I will be using a different SP. So, I cannot have a single login access all of the subscriptions, and thus the need to relogin with each run. In my case, each subscription represents a different customer of ours, so a single SP accessing all of those is a huge security breach and really isn't an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `AZURE_CONFIG_DIR` environment variable does the trick as described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/use_cli_effectively.md#concurrent-builds).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to keep `az login` as it is, remove `az account set` and use `--subscription` argument for each command instead.

You can see that `~/.azure/azureProfile.json` contains tenantId and user information for each subscription and `~/.azure/accessTokens.json` contains all tokens.

So, if you precise each time your subscription explicitly you will not depend on common user context.

I have my `Account 1` for subscription `xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx`, and `Account 2` for subscription `yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy` and I do:

```sh
az login # Account 1
az login # Account 2
az group list --subscription "xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"
az group list --subscription "yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy"
```

and it works well under the same unix user

Comment: @ZhulianGinev you give me the reason "cannot use same SP", so you can login each time with different SP, just do not execute `az account set` and precise subscription ID. I have several accounts with several subscriptions and I find them all in `~/.azure/` until I do not execute `az logout --username`